# Restful service always returns null value in Xamarin Forms

Tags: visual-studio-2013, xamarin, xamarin-studio, xamarin.forms

i am developing an app using "Xamarin Forms", and i'm using Visual Studio 2013 to develop the app.
Here my problem is,
in my app i'm using restful services to Post/Get the data.
The entire code wrote in "Xamarin Shared Project"
Here is my code:

```
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Net.Http;

namespace Sher.Services
{
    public class CustomerService : ICustomerService
    {
        public async Task<string> TopEntries(String uri)
        {
            var client = new HttpClient();
            var result = await client.GetStringAsync(uri); //"http://api.ihackernews.com/page"
            return result;
        }
    }

    public interface ICustomerService
    {
        Task<string> TopEntries();
    }
}
```

Here i'm facing small problem.
i am able to call the service method and the service method execute in my server.
But the return result is gives always "NULL". i don't know why.
can any one help me to solve this problem.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: How do you know if it is really null? Mind that async method will exit immediately and continue when data is fetched in such cases.

Comment: @MihaMarkic when i execute line by line, after this line "var result = await client.GetStringAsync(uri);" controler moves to end of the method. it's  not move to next line.

Comment: When you calling your TopEntries(string) function try do it like : TopEntries(string).ContinueWith(t=> ... ); and check t for exception

Comment: If you can package a small example up and email it, I will take a look.  My contact details are on my Profile.

Answer (score 0):

Yup, this is how async methods work. When an async call (await keyword) is made they exit and continue from that point when async calls is completed.
Try putting a breakpoint in "return result;" line.

Comment: i put the breakpoint in "return result" line. but no use. how can i solve this problem. is there any other way to solve this problem.

Comment: put that "var result = await ..." in try/catch. It is probably an exception you are getting.

Comment: i put the code in try/catch, but no use. again it moves to end of the method.

Comment: You have to wait for async call to finish. Then it will hit breakpoint. Unless there is a problem with debugger. Try also using Debug.WriteLine in addition to breakpoint.

Comment: When you calling your TopEntries(string) function try do it like : TopEntries(string).ContinueWith(t=> ... ); and check t for exception